# MySQL UPDATE query stuck on "Sending Data" State

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, update, mysql-5.6

I am having difficulty getting an `UPDATE` query to successfully execute, due to the process getting stuck on "Sending Data" state.

I feel this differs from [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347193) about the "Sending Data" state because it is happening during an UPDATE query, which MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html) leads me to believe shouldn't happen. (?)

Here are the two relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `CustomerVisits` (
  `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `MerchantID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CTime` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CustomerID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `SinceLastVisit` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `CTime` (`CTime`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `LocationID_OrderID_CTime` (`LocationID`, `OrderID`, `CTime`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `OrderID` (`OrderID`),
  INDEX `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `VisitDiffTimes` (
  `DiffTime` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `MerchantID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CustomerID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CTime` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MerchantID`, `OrderID`, `CustomerID`) USING HASH,
  INDEX `DiffTime` (`DiffTime`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`CustomerVisits` has 12 million rows, and `VisitDiffTimes` has 4 million rows.

The `CustomerVisits.SinceLastVisit` column is currently all `NULL` - I want to populate it with the following query:

```
UPDATE CustomerVisits V
  JOIN VisitDiffTimes D
    ON V.OrderID = D.OrderID AND V.CustomerID = D.CustomerID
   SET V.SinceLastVisit = D.DiffTime
```

The output of `EXPLAIN` for this query is:

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys       key       key_len  ref        rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE       D      index  NULL                DiffTime  9        NULL       4065127  Using index
1   SIMPLE       V      ref    OrderID,CustomerID  OrderID   4        D.OrderID  1        Using where
```

Is there some problem with either my query or the table definitions that can make this operation faster?

---

## Update

I have implemented RolandoMySQLDBA's suggestions below, but unfortunately the query is still running on and on without end.

I have included below the result of `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS`. I see that the engine is reporting `0.00 updates/s`, so I am concerned that this query is not on the track towards completion in any reasonable time frame.

```
=====================================
2015-09-24 15:55:40 7f9d02217700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 7 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 65705 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 46262 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 111963
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2282726
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 3647755
Mutex spin waits 3344497, rounds 28268630, OS waits 400079
RW-shared spins 2898160, rounds 69659833, OS waits 1747791
RW-excl spins 365077, rounds 10516470, OS waits 86454
Spin rounds per wait: 8.45 mutex, 24.04 RW-shared, 28.81 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 26361458
Purge done for trx's n:o < 26361455 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 1926
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 1595, OS thread handle 0x7f9d02217700, query id 70163629 (IP Address) (Username) init
SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 26361457, ACTIVE 2764 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
50350 lock struct(s), heap size 4617768, 181942 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1579, OS thread handle 0x7f9d02299700, query id 70163374 (IP Address) (Username) Sending data
UPDATE SaleOrderPayment P
  JOIN SaleOrderPayment_Diff_Merchant T
    ON P.OrderID = T.OrderID AND P.CustomerID = T.CustomerID
   SET P.SinceLastVisitMerchant = T.DiffTime
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
137002174 OS file reads, 20383973 OS file writes, 844094 OS fsyncs
18277.25 reads/s, 16771 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 2723, seg size 2725, 5175728 merges
merged operations:
 insert 13665166, delete mark 8438509, delete 8253
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 415109, node heap has 71 buffer(s)
443.79 hash searches/s, 32426.94 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 125059941125
Log flushed up to   125059941125
Pages flushed up to 125059941125
Last checkpoint at  125059941125
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
11664686 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 214630400; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 172905
Buffer pool size   12799
Free buffers       0
Database pages     12447
Old database pages 4602
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1352321, not young 1300347433
0.00 youngs/s, 147255.82 non-youngs/s
Pages read 144210003, created 530043, written 12368276
18709.33 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 876 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 983 / 1000
Pages read ahead 438.79/s, evicted without access 66.99/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 12447, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[915059]:cur[17449], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 24315, id 140312316348160, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 36456765, updated 13112249, deleted 16214487, read 688045738
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 32871.02 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

---

## Update 2

Here is the updated `EXPLAIN` output after following RolandoMySQLDBA's suggestions below.

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys                  key         key_le   ref           rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE       D      index  PRIMARY                        DiffTime    9        NULL          4044212  Using index
1   SIMPLE       V      ref    CustomerID,OrderID_CustomerID  CustomerID  5        D.CustomerID  1        Using where
```

---

## Update 3

I have implemented RolandoMySQLDBA's **Suggestion 4** below; the updated `EXPLAIN` output is:

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys                          key                 key_len  ref                     rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE       D      index  PRIMARY                                DiffTime            9        NULL                    4044212  Using index
1   SIMPLE       V      ref    OrderID_CustomerID,CustomerID_OrderID  OrderID_CustomerID  9        D.OrderID,D.CustomerID  1        NULL
```

Comment: Please add the explain plan of the query as it should look different with the indexes.

Comment: I have updated the question above, @RolandoMySQLDBA - please see "Update 2"

Comment: I have accepted your answer, @RolandoMySQLDBA, thanks for your help! The query has finally moved out of "Sending Data" state and is now "Updating Reference Tables" - so the query will probably complete within an hour or so. It seems that your latest index change made the `OrderID_CustomerID` index more appealing to the optimizer - perhaps I could have used `FORCE INDEX` instead, to similar effect?

Comment: Doing `FORCE INDEX` might have done it as well. Try it our and see ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PROBLEM

In the EXPLAIN plan, `select_type` is `SIMPLE`.

That's a full index scan `VisitDiffTimes` and range scan on `CustomerVisits`.

## SUGGESTION #1

You need to reorder the columns in the PRIMARY KEY of `VisitDiffTimes`

```
ALTER TABLE VisitDiffTimes DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE VisitDiffTimes ADD PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`, `CustomerID`, `MerchantID`);
```

This will eliminate the full scan on `VisitDiffTimes`

## SUGGESTION #2 (Optional)

Create a compound index on those two columns for `CustomerVisits`

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerVisits
    DROP INDEX OrderID,
    ADD INDEX OrderID_CustomerID_ndx (OrderID,CustomerID)
;
```

The JOIN may end up cleaner

## SUGGESTION #3 (Optional)

Set the join_buffer_size to 16M

Add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
join_buffer_size = 16M
```

You don't have to restart. Just login as `root@localhost` and run

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## SUGGESTION #4 (Optional)

Another Index with columns `(CustomerID,OrderID)`

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerVisits
    DROP INDEX CustomerID,
    ADD INDEX CustomerID_OrderID_ndx (CustomerID,OrderID)
;
```

Comment: Thank you @RolandoMySQLDBA - I have followed your three suggestions and the query is currently running. It's at about 11 minutes running in "Sending Data" state.

As far as the `select_type` of `SIMPLE`, I feel that is to be expected, as I want every value in `VisitDiffTimes` to be matched up with the corresponding row(s) in `CustomerVisits`.

Comment: Suggested another index. Please create the index under `SUGGESTION #4`, show the EXPLAIN plan, and try the query again.

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA - I have updated the question with `EXPLAIN` output following your suggested index change.